# how to remove duplicates from 2 joins in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i am using spatie laravel query builder to make some filters for my project and i have the code as below :

```
public function scopeFilter()
    {
        $data = QueryBuilder::for(Accommodation::class)
            ->allowedFilters([
                AllowedFilter::scope('bed_count'),
                AllowedFilter::scope('filter_price'),
                AllowedFilter::scope('filter_date'),
                AllowedFilter::scope('discounts'),
                AllowedFilter::scope('name'),
                AllowedFilter::exact('grade_stars'),
                AllowedFilter::exact('city_id'),
                AllowedFilter::exact('is_recommended'),
                AllowedFilter::exact('accommodation_type_id'),
                AllowedFilter::scope('accommodation_facility')
//                'name',
            ])
            ->allowedAppends(['cheapestroom'])
            ->allowedIncludes(['gallery','city','accommodationRooms','accommodationRooms.roomPricingHistorySearch','discounts','prices'])
            ->allowedSorts([
                AllowedSort::custom('discount', new DiscountSort() ,'amount'),
                AllowedSort::custom('price', new PriceSort() ,'price'),
            ])
            ->paginate(12);
        return FilterResource::collection($data);
```

now i have 1 sort and 2 filters which is so important for me here is the code for them

## sort

```
  $data = $query->join('accommodation_rooms as cr', 'accommodations.id', '=', 'cr.accommodation_id')
            ->join('room_pricing_histories as dr','cr.id', '=', 'room_pricing_histories.accommodation_room_id')
//            ->select('cr.id')
            ->orderBy('dr.sales_price', 'desc')
            ->select('dr.sales_price', 'accommodations.*')
            ->groupBy('dr.sales_price','accommodations.id');
        $direction = $descending ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';

        return $data;
```

## first filter which is wrriten as scope

```
 public function scopeFilterPrice(Builder $query, $start_price, $end_price): Builder
    {
        $data = $query->leftjoin('accommodation_rooms as ar','ar.id','=','accommodations.id')
            ->leftjoin('room_pricing_histories','room_pricing_histories.id','=','ar.id')
            ->select('accommodations.*')
            ->where('room_pricing_histories.sales_price', '>', $start_price)
            ->where('room_pricing_histories.sales_price', '<', $end_price);
        return $data;
    }
```

## secound filter as scope too

```
public function scopeFilterDate(Builder $query,$from_date,$to_date): Builder{

        $data = $query->leftjoin('accommodation_rooms as br','br.id','=','accommodations.id')
            ->Join('room_capacity_histories','room_capacity_histories.id','=','br.id')
            ->select('accommodations.*')
            ->whereDate('room_capacity_histories.from_date', '>', $from_date)
            ->whereDate('room_capacity_histories.to_date', '<', $to_date);

        return $data;
```

but this will bring me duplicate data no matter what groupby or other thing i use i want to know if there is any possibilty for me to remove duplicates on resource or some where else.

### NOTE

i did use `->unique()` but it wont have the structure of pagination any more which cause me a problem so i want the structure of pagination first . here is the raw query :

```
"select `dr`.`sales_price`, `accommodations`.* from `accommodations` left join `accommodation_rooms` as `ar` on `ar`.`id` = `accommodations`.`id` left join `room_pricing_histories` on `room_pricing_histories`.`id` = `ar`.`id` left join `accommodation_rooms` as `br` on `br`.`id` = `accommodations`.`id` inner join `room_capacity_histories` on `room_capacity_histories`.`id` = `br`.`id` inner join `accommodation_rooms` as `cr` on `accommodations`.`id` = `cr`.`accommodation_id` inner join `room_pricing_histories` as `dr` on `cr`.`id` = `room_pricing_histories`.`accommodation_room_id` where `room_pricing_histories`.`sales_price` > ? and `room_pricing_histories`.`sales_price` < ? and date(`room_capacity_histories`.`from_date`) > ? and date(`room_capacity_histories`.`to_date`) < ? group by `dr`.`sales_price`, `accommodations`.`id` order by `dr`.`sales_price` desc"
```

thanks

Comment: I think ->distinct() is what you're looking for.

Comment: nope sir its not working

Comment: did you try 'distinct' inside select() ?

Comment: @AnatoliyR how to distinct inside the select ?

Comment: not sure. but something like ->select('distinct accommodations.*') 

that is not recommended by Laravel, but may work, actually ->select('accommodations.*')->distinct() may not work, you need to use something like table('accommodations')->distinct() instead. Finally you can try filter dups in the result set collection

Comment: I believe in order to use distinct with pagination you have to do something like this: ->distinct()->paginate(12, ['Table1.Column1, Table1.Column2']);

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code will work for you

**Sort**

```
$data = $query->join('accommodation_rooms as cr', 'accommodations.id', '=', 'cr.accommodation_id')
             ->join('accommodation_rooms as cr2', 'accommodations.id', '=', 'cr2.accommodation_id')
            ->leftJoin('room_pricing_histories as dr','cr.id', '=', 'room_pricing_histories.accommodation_room_id')
//            ->select('cr.id')

            ->orderBy('dr.sales_price', 'desc')
            ->where('cr.id !=','cr2.id')
            ->select('dr.sales_price', 'accommodations.*')
            ->groupBy('dr.sales_price','accommodations.id');
        $direction = $descending ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';

        return $data;
```